# definition of "no less a person than"

Tags: definition

The Collins Dictionary has the following definition for "no less a person than":

> a person of no lower importance, rank, etc. than

I'm wondering if it's an accurate definition.
It makes the following sentence sound as if John and the president are not one and the same person:

> John is powerful because he is no less a person than the president.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking whether your example text would still be valid ***if John is in fact the president**?* My answer to that it "No, it's not valid to say someone is no less a person than himself" - not because it violates any *syntactic* principle, but because it violates Grice's Maxim regarding "pointless" additional information in an utterance.

Comment: John is powerful because he is **none other than** the president.

Comment: John is powerful because he is the president.

Comment: Do you think the definition is correct then?

Comment: Consider this example, which also uses "no less a person than": The message came from no less a person than the prime minister.

Comment: By the Collins definition, it would (incorrectly) mean the message came from someone who was of no lower importance, rank, etc. than the prime minister. This in turn implies that someone was not the prime minister.

Comment: The example in the OP isn't comparable to the example you've just given, because in the latter, no particular person had been identified previously in the sentence. That sentence implies that the message came from the prime minister. If the example in the OP (John ... is no less a person than...) actually came from edited English text, please provide a source.

Comment: What are the conditons on the use of "no less a person than" if it is is used to show identity as in the latter example? Why can't the phrase be used in the OP example with the identity meaning?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Consider the following quote: "That," said Heywood, turning into their former path, "that was Fang, the Sword-Pen, so-called. Very clever chap. Of the two most dangerous men in the district, he's one." They had swung along briskly for several minutes, before he added: "The other most dangerous man--you've met him already. If I'm not mistaken, he's no less a person than the Reverend James Earle."

Comment: First, I assume you know what purple prose is. That source of that quote is ultraviolet.

Comment: Second, Apollyon, we are both humans. I am a person and you are no less a person than I. Yet, I am not you, and you are not I. We can conclude now that "no less a person than" is not an idiom with a single fixed meaning, but a phrase whose meaning depends on context. Sometimes it identifies a person with an alternate name or description, but sometimes not.

Comment: What is purple prose and "ultraviolet"?

Answer (score 1):

The Collins definition is quite a poor one. Literally, the words "no less a person than" mean "a person of no lower importance, rank, etc. than", but that implies they could also refer to someone more powerful, like a King or an Emperor, which is not the case.

The structure **"no less a/an" + A + "than" + B** has the idiomatic meaning of **"a significant/important A: B"**. So, in your example, it means, "John was a significant person: namely, the President."

Comment: Some people think the "a significant/important A: B" meaning is not possible with the example in the OP. And they seem to be native speakers.

Comment: It can have the meaning Jack O'Flaherty is arguing for, but not only that one. The quote you dug up about Heywood exactly matches the OP example, as far as I can tell, and goes against what Jack said about whether that particular "B" person had been previously identified. There might be a quibble that the person's name hadn't been used yet, but I can't see that argument holding water. And for what it's worth, I'm a native speaker and have been teaching ESL for 15+ years.

Comment: @gotube I haven't argued that the phrase does or doesn't identify one person; I claim that Apollyon's example starting with   "John" doesn't supply enough information to say whether John is the president. The example that I said it wasn't parallel to (the message came from no less a person than the  prime minister) is one that strongly suggests that a single person is being identified.